# Returning std::vector from an immediate function

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, stdvector, consteval

Since C++20, `std::vector` can be used in constant expressions. And as far as I known, current C++ permits dynamically allocate memory under the condition that any such allocation is deallocated by the time the constant expression is "over".

However, I encounter that in case of immediate function the rules might be different. Please consider the example:

```
consteval auto getVec() {
    return std::vector<int>(9);
}

static_assert( getVec().size() == 9 );
```

Here immediate `consteval` function `getVec` returns not-empty `std::vector`, size of which is verified in a constant expression.

I expected that this code would compile, because all deallocations must be done automatically, and indeed it is accepted in Clang with `libc++`.

But MSVC complains:

```
error C7595: 'getVec': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
note: (sub-)object points to memory which was heap allocated during constant evaluation
fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

and GCC behaves similarly:

```
error: 'getVec()()' is not a constant expression because it refers to a result of 'operator new'
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d736qr3hh

Which compiler is correct here?

Comment: It will be valid in C++23 because the rules changed so that a call to a `consteval` function  inside a manifestly-constant evaluated expression is no longer by itself an immediate invocation, which seems to be what you expect of C++20.

Comment: @user17732522, thanks. It seems that no compiler implements new rules from C++23 yet: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jMKW4zaaY

Comment: The changes are in [P2564](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1223) and it was accepted only in February of 2023 as response to a NB comment to the C++23 draft, so it is not that surprising that it hasn't been implemented yet. Actually, according to [the minutes](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/n4940.pdf) of the relevant meeting it was even accepted as DR against C++20, so once implemented your code should be good in C++20 mode too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is fixed with [P2564R3](https://wg21.link/P2564R3) being accepted as a defect report for C++20. It allows `getVec()` to be a subexpression of a larger constant expression without being a constant expression by itself.

LLVM 17 and the upcomming GCC 14 implement it. For MSVC there is a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Implement-C20-DR:-P2564/10514467).

- https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/W7bEaMq17

---

The original reason for the problem was this:

[[expr.prim.id]p3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.id#3):

> A potentially-evaluated *id-expression* that denotes an immediate function ([dcl.constexpr]) shall appear only
>
> - as a subexpression of an immediate invocation, or
> - in an immediate function context ([expr.const])

[[expr.const]p13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#13):

> An expression or conversion is in an *immediate function context* if it is potentially evaluated and its innermost non-block scope is a function parameter scope of an immediate function. An expression or conversion is an *immediate invocation* if it is potentially-evaluated explicit or implicit invocation of an immediate function and is not in an immediate function context. An immediate invocation shall be a constant expression.

`static_assert( getVec().size() == 9 );` is not in an immediate function context. Therefore, the explicit invocation `getVec()` is an immediate invocation, so it needs to produce a constant expression. `getVec()` by itself is not a constant expression since it doesn't deallocate the memory allocated by new.

For comparison, the following do compile https://godbolt.org/z/9KqhY7oP8

```cpp
consteval auto getVec() {
    return std::vector<int>(9);
}

consteval auto getVecSize() {
    return getVec().size();
}

static_assert(getVecSize() == 9);
static_assert([]() consteval { return getVec().size() == 9; }());

consteval void InAnImmediateFunctionContext() {
    static_assert(getVec().size() == 9);
}
```